# erro no accuracy_score da biblioteca sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, sklearn

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
# retorna 1 se houver mais de 1 número 1
treino_x = [[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,1]]
teste_x =[[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[1,1,1]]
teste_y = np.array([0,0,0,1])
treino_y = np.array([1,1,0,1])

modelo = LinearSVC()
modelo.fit(treino_x,treino_y)
predict = modelo.predict(teste_x)
accuracy_score(teste_y,teste_x)
```

tentei treinar esse modelo, mas retona:

ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and multilabel-indicator targets
 alguém poderia me ajudar? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao fazer `accuracy_score(teste_y,teste_x)`, você está comparando a saída esperada (`teste_y`) com a entrada do modelo (`teste_x`).

O certo é comparar a saída esperada com a resposta do modelo:

```
accuracy_score(teste_y, predict)
```

Comment: verdade! obrigado por me ajudar, sou um pouco novo nesse mundo, mas sangue nos olhos e vamos ajeitar isso ai :D

Answer (score 0):

Em algoritmos de aprendizagem de máquina existem os dados de entrada, que geralmente são armazenados na variável `X`, como `X_train` e `X_test` e variáveis armazenando os rótulos referentes aos dados de entrada, usualmente armazenados na variável `y`, como `y_train` e `y_test`.

Como o AlexCiuffa mencionou, o método `accuracy_score` tem como parâmetros o rótulo dos dados corretos, e o rótulo dos dados que seu modelo previu.

O correto seria `accuracy_score(teste_y, predict)`

Outra observação é que todos os modelos da biblioteca Scikit-Learn possuem um método para computar a acurácia média, sem a necessidade de importar outro módulo.

No caso do `LinearSVC`, existe o método `score`, que desempenha o mesmo papel do `accuracy_score`, recebendo os dados de teste e os rótulos de teste.

O uso em seu código seria o seguinte:

```
modelo.score(teste_x, teste_y)
```